# Hashtable returns value for wrong key

Tags: java, properties, hashtable, openehr

I have a `Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>>` where I want to get the hashtable with a key, but it returns the value for the other key.
Here is the code:

```
Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>> testFormProperties = 
         formProperties.getFormProperties();

Hashtable<String, String> treeProps = 
        (Hashtable<String, String>)testFormProperties.get("clusterTreeItem");
```

now `treeProps` contains

```
freeTextLabel= {
     guiType=TreeItem, 
     label=freeText, 
     path=/data[at0001]/items[openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.cluster_test_data_types.v1]/items[at0001]
}
```

instead of

```
clusterTreeItem={
    guiType=TreeItem,
    label=freeText, 
    path=/data[at0001]/items[openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.cluster_test_data_types.v1]/items[at0001]
}
```

here the content of the testFormProperties Hashtable as per debugger:

```
{
   freeTextLabel =
     {guiType=TreeItem, label=freeText, path=/data[at0001]/items[openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.cluster_test_data_types.v1]/items[at0001]
     }, 
  clusterTreeItem = 
     {guiType=TreeItem, label=freeText, path=/data[at0001]/items[openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.cluster_test_data_types.v1]/items[at0001]
     }
}
```

I got the same results with `Properties<String, Hashtable<String, String>`

Can someone explain what is wrong and why?

Comment: Your post is way too dirty to read. Please purify it first.

Comment: Both the keys `freeTextLabel` and `clusterTreeItem` have the same values. How do you know its returning the value for the other key?

Comment: this is another bug when i put the values the values added first are overwritten. still checking for that

Comment: I resolved that bug Neo mentioned. I also changed to HashMap based on the discussion in this forum.

Comment: Now it works correct. but still wondering: the keys are different, why does it matter that values are the same... keys `freeTextLabel` versus `clusterTreeItem`...

Comment: The question is not clear. Please use code that we can run and see for ourselves what the output is and state what you expected the output to be.